# compare List to Firebase Android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

I have a list called "categories" and I need to compare each entry of that list to the "cat" attribute of all the entries in my Firebase. If they match, I retrieve the data. So each entry of the list will match several entries in my database and I need to retrieve all those entries at once.

Here is the code I'm trying to use but it isn't working

```
final static List<String> categories = new ArrayList<>();

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

for (int j = 0; j < categories.size(); j++){
           databaseReference.child("Advertiser").orderByChild("cat").equalTo(categories.get(j)).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                final ArrayList<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshots){
                    final String cat = snapshot.child("cat").getValue(String.class);
                    //etc..
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

This is the code I'm using to retrieve info about the liked pages and populating the List categories

```
public static void getLikedPageInfo(LoginResult login_result){

    GraphRequest data_request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
            login_result.getAccessToken(),
            new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(JSONObject json_object, GraphResponse response) {
                    try {
                        // convert Json object into Json array
                        JSONArray posts = json_object.getJSONObject("likes").optJSONArray("data");
                        for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                            JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
                            //String id = post.optString("id");
                            String category = post.optString("category");
                            String name = post.optString("name");
                            //int count = post.optInt("likes");

                            if (!categories.contains(category)){
                                categories.add(category);
                            }
                            Log.e("name: ", name+" category: "+category);
                        }
                        Log.e("category", categories.toString());
                    } catch(Exception e){

                    }

                }
            });
    Bundle permission_param = new Bundle();
    permission_param.putString("fields", "likes{id,category,name,location,likes}");
    data_request.setParameters(permission_param);
    data_request.executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: Not working how? It's not fetching any results, not the results you'd like, throws an error, .. ?

Comment: Right, but there's nothing in your categories List? So obviously it wouldn't loop over anything. Unless you've filled it somewhere else. Also, you don't seem to have replaced your code with the piece of code I gave you?

Comment: @PieterLaebens I output the categories in my logcat and I can confirm that it is NOT empty. I did replace my code with the one you give me, but only in my android studio and not in the original question here

Comment: Okay, can you place a couple of Logs on random places? See if onDataChange is ever called, see what the value of categories.get(j) is for every iteration of the loop, make sure nothing's wrong there.

Comment: @PieterLaebens I'm populating categories in the same activity I'm retrieving data. When I output categories in the method I'm populating it, it displays. Now the code for retrieving data is in the onCreate method. I tried displaying categories outside the for loop but inside the onCreate method and it is empty. What I understood is that when the app runs, it is trying to loop through an empty list first, then after that the list is populated. Do you know how do I get the populated list in the onCreate method?

Comment: Are you getting your categories from Firebase as well?

Comment: @PieterLaebens no in fact I'm retrieving info about a user's Facebook liked pages and I'm storing the categories in my List 'categories'. I'm not even storing that on Firebase because different users will like different pages.

Comment: I'm guessing you're fetching the categories from Facebook in some kind of async method, could you try fetching the Advertisers in the onCompleted part of that async method? I'd have to see the part where you're loading the categories to help you out with that.

Comment: @PieterLaebens I just edited my post. You can have a look.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're looping over an empty ArrayList

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  // You create a new ArrayList and then loop over it without actually putting anything in there.
  final ArrayList<DataSnapshot> dataSnapshots = new ArrayList<>();
  for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshots){
    final String cat = snapshot.child("cat").getValue(String.class);
    //etc..
  }
}
```

This should do the trick.

```
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
  for (DataSnapshot snapshot: dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
    final String cat = snapshot.child("cat").getValue(String.class);
    //etc..
  }
}
```

Does this work?

```
public static void getLikedPageInfo(LoginResult login_result){

GraphRequest data_request = GraphRequest.newMeRequest(
        login_result.getAccessToken(),
        new GraphRequest.GraphJSONObjectCallback() {
            @Override
            public void onCompleted(JSONObject json_object, GraphResponse response) {
                try {
                    // convert Json object into Json array
                    JSONArray posts = json_object.getJSONObject("likes").optJSONArray("data");
                    for (int i = 0; i < posts.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject post = posts.optJSONObject(i);
                        //String id = post.optString("id");
                        String category = post.optString("category");
                        String name = post.optString("name");
                        //int count = post.optInt("likes");

                        if (!categories.contains(category)){
                            categories.add(category);
                            databaseReference.child("Advertiser").orderByChild("cat").equalTo(category).addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
                                @Override
                                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                                    for (DataSnapshot advertiser : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                                        final String categoryString = advertiser.child("cat").getValue(String.class);
                                    }
                                }

                                @Override
                                public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

                                }
                            });
                        }
                        Log.e("name: ", name+" category: "+category);
                    }
                    Log.e("category", categories.toString());
                } catch(Exception e){

                }

            }
        });
    Bundle permission_param = new Bundle();
    permission_param.putString("fields", "likes{id,category,name,location,likes}");
    data_request.setParameters(permission_param);
    data_request.executeAsync();
}
```

Comment: it's not working. i'm using a Log.e to try to display the String cat but it ain't showing in my logcat

Comment: It's working fine for me, is that initial loop even running? Did you fill categories correctly? Can you edit your initial question with the part where you initialise categories?

Comment: Also, where exactly are you logging these values? Inside of the Firebase callback?

Comment: Updated my answer

Comment: Brilliant mate! it's working. but one thing though, each of the category may match several entries in my database and I need to retrieve them all at once. does your code cater for that?

Comment: The onDataChange should return an array of every Advertiser that has that specific category. So that should be fine.

Comment: i'm having difficulties to put the attributes of each advertiser in a hashmap, can you help one last time please?

Comment: If you edit the question with the part you're having issues with, with some comments explaining what's going wrong, sure.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure what you're trying to do, maybe you should make a new question since this one is pretty much answered. Or, you can try reading other questions a bit more.

Comment: please discard my previous comment; I kinda got confused. Your answer works perfectly. Thanks for sticking with me from start to finish. Much appreciated!

Comment: Glad to help :)